# WPF Drag-and-Drop Custom Class

Tags: wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop

I start the operation like this:

```
Public Sub cLinkOut_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    'Trace.WriteLine("mousedown: " & ObjectKey)
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(TryCast(Me, CellContainer), ObjectKey, DragDropEffects.All)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

"Me" is a custom class called, CellContainer, which is really a canvas with added properties.

I handle the drop like this:

```
Public Sub cLinkIn_Drop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
    Dim cSource As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat)
    Dim cTarget As String = TryCast(e.OriginalSource, CellContainer).ObjectKey
    Trace.WriteLine("srce: " & cSource & ", targ: " & cTarget)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

The problem is that e.OriginalSource shows up as a Canvas, not a CellContainer, and cTarget is set to Nothing.  How can I pass the entire CellContainer (not just the ObjectKey) from the Drag to the Drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
Public Sub cLinkOut_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim data As DataObject = New DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, Me)
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(CType(e.Source, DependencyObject), data, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Public Sub cLinkIn_Drop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs)
    Dim c As CellContainer = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable), CellContainer)
    Dim cSource As String = c.ObjectKey
    Dim cTarget As String = Me.ObjectKey
    Trace.WriteLine("srce: " & cSource & ", targ: " & cTarget)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```